# List of numbers without repetition

Tags: c#

I need to print random numbers from 1 to 99 without repeating them.
The following code gives me stack overflow.

```
int newNumb= Random.Range(1, 99);
if(acum.Count > 0)
{
    while (acum.Contains(newNumb))
    {
         newNumb= Random.Range(1, 99);
    }
}
```

Comment: shuffle a list containing all numbers from 1 to 99.

Comment: There's no way you are getting a stack overflow from that code

Comment: How would you do it ?

Comment: @Charleh, your probably right, but you could still get a stackoverflow, your just assuming you know the type of acum

Comment: [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show us how `acum` is declared, nor does it show why `acum.count` would be greater than zero.  Assuming those two issues are resolved sensibly - your code gets a stack overflow because there's nothing to stop it running for ever.  But @Jarod42 is correct, there are better ways to do this.

Comment: This is the third time in 3 days I've seen this question :-D

Comment: @johnny5 good point :) natural assumption would probably be `List<T>` due to `.Count` and `.Contains`, but I based my comment on the question content and reputation of the OP which suggests a certain level of experience!

Comment: @FrankBoyne but that's still not a stack overflow...

Comment: @Charleh fair point.  I suspect the infinite loop is leading to the overflow but without a [mcve] I'm just guessing.  We don't even know the type of the variable `Random`.  We might assume it's an instance of `System.Random` but `Range` isn't a method on that class.  Is `Range` an extension method on `System.Random` or is the variable `Random` some other type?  Likewise we don't know what kind of container `acum` is nor do we see the code that adds new numbers to the container as they are generated.  Who knows what else we might not be seeing?

Answer (score 4):

The typical solution to this problem is to generate the *sequential ordered* range from 1 to 99 and then *shuffle* it:

```
static Random _random = new Random();

public static void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> items)
{
    for (int i = thisList.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int j = _random.Next(0, i);
        T tmp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[j];
        items[j] = tmp;
    }
}

var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,99).ToList();
Shuffle(numbers);
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
     Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: I think you could stop your `for` loop at `i>0`.  When `i==0` you're going to call  `random.Next(0,0)` which will return 0.  Swapping `items[0]` with `items[0]` isn't wrong per se but you don't really need to do it.

Comment: @FrankBoyne fixed, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a new list (instead of in-place replacing) to make this more functional (and you could even have a `yield return` there...)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It can be. Depends on if you want to allocate new memory or not.

Comment: The upper bound on `Random.Next` is exclusive, so this may be an example of implementing Sattolo's algorithm when intending to implement Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a list of random integers, each time a different one, and add it to a list.

The shuffle method is better, but since the range is so limited, also discarding duplicate numbers could work.

Over 100 runs, measuring the elapsed time with a `StopWatch()`, the list generation never went over 200 Ticks.
The shuffled list 5x times (1029~1395 Ticks) on my machine.

If the list count is set to a value > then the upper range limit (100+ in this case), the the generation procedure will of course never end. There are not enough distinct random values to fill the list.

```
Random random = new Random();

    List<int> acum = new List<int>();

    while (acum.Count < 99)
    {
        int Number = random.Next(1, 100);
        if (!acum.Contains(Number))
        {
            acum.Add(Number);
        }
    }
```

To verify the result, order the list and see that it's ordered from 1 to 99:

```
List<int> acum2 = acum.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

the best way to do this would be to generate all the necessary numbers, and pull from that list until its empty, creating a new order; this is commonly known as shuffling.

your current code takes way too long, you need to track which numbers have been chosen, and only choose from the remaining ones. in psudocode

```
generate list
while list not empty
    choose number from list
    remove it from list
    add to new list
```

Comment: Perfect. It's true that what you say works but why does my code give me a stack overflow?

`            for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++)
            {
                int newNumb= Random.Range(1, 9);
                if(acum.Count > 0)
                {
                    while (acum.Contains(newNumb))
                    {
                        nuevo = Random.Range(1, 9);
                    }
                }
                acum.Add(newNumb);
            }`

Comment: @Nogerad no idea, you shouldn't get a stack overflow, but your fragment will run forever since there are only 8 numbers [1,9], and you are trying to force 100 unique numbers.

Comment: what is solution?

Answer (score -1):

Do this simply:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

var resultList = list.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Or as suggested by @Camilo:

```
var resultList = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 99)
    .OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
```

### UPDATE

This solution seems to be inefficient. Please use **fischer-yates** shuffle (shown in @Joel's answer).

Comment: Or... `Enumerable.Range(0, 99)` and avoid a loop

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, added to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Order does not work, use OrderBy

Comment: @HusseinGolshani, thanks, I just wrote the code on the fly.

Comment: Strictly speaking the request was for the numbers 1..99 not 0..98.  :-)

Comment: It's also very bad to order by a new guid instead of doing a real shuffle. This can be _biased_ (not as random as it seems), and it can lead to extra loops and sub-optimal performance in the sorting algorithm because it will generate guids for the same item in the sequence more than once; this can even cause an exception.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, how is that, could you clarify more please?

Comment: When sorting, an algorithm will go through a sequence comparing pairs of values, and maybe swapping them. This code generates a new guid for **every** comparison. Say the sequence includes number 13, 30, and 45. It's possible to compare 13 and 30 so that 13 comes first. Then compare 30 and 45 so that 30 comes first (13, then 30, then 45), and then also compare 13 and 45 so that 45 should come before 13. It's just bad. Don't do it this way. It's not that hard to write a real fischer-yates shuffle.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, what about using Singleton `Guid` (or I mean a short term existing Guid)?

Comment: Doesn't matter. This still generates a different guid for a value every time that value comes up for comparison. You _can_ use linq to do this, but you have to first `.Select()` to an anoymous type with fields for the original value and generated guid (so the guid is preserved), `.OrderBy()` to sort by the generated guid from the select, and then `Select()` back to just the values...

Comment: ...but this is still much slower than fischer-yates because the sort has to look at each item and put it into a specific spot via a series of compares, rather than just looking at each spot and selecting a random item once. It also still has potential for bias.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I do not understand how using singleton generates a new Guid? Please Check the update (I am just trying to understand why).

Comment: The enhancement is worse... now every item has the **same** value.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, ok got it. Thank you.

Comment: Think about what the `i => Guid.NewGuid()` expression does. When the sorting algorithm needs to compare two values, this is the code it uses (for _both_ values) to determine how those values are compared. So every time any comparison is made in in the process of performing the `OrderBy()`, it generates a whole new guid _again_, even if it's already done it before for that value. In a shuffle, that would be okay... but `OrderBy()` is written to produce _ordered_ results, and this can lead it to strange places, and take much longer than necessary to get there.

Comment: This is why javascript's sorting algorithm, for example, instead asks for a function that looks at **two** values (`a` and `b`) instead of just one `i`), where the function just does the compare... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score -2):

Non efficient way (see comments):

```
Random rand = new Random();
HashSet<int> randomHashSet = new HashSet<int>();
while (randomHashSet.Count < 99)
    randomHashSet.Add(rand.Next(1, 100));
List<int> randomList = randomHashSet.ToList();
```

**Update**

Efficient way:

```
Random r = new Random();
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 99).ToList();
for (int i = 0, j = r.Next(0, 99); i < 99; i++, j = r.Next(0, 99))
    result[i] = result[i] + result[j] - (result[j] = result[i]); // Swap
```

Comment: This will duplicate a lot of numbers.

Comment: This will be insanely slow, you might generate thousands and thousands of useless numbers

Comment: No, Hashset does not allow Duplicate!

Comment: This question is not about performance problem!

Comment: @HusseinGolshani no you don't understand, every duplicate will be ignored, and this code could run forever.

Comment: as @esoterik said, there will be a duplicate, but they will be ignored (which is just a waste of CPU ticks).

Comment: Yes, they will be ignored, which makes this algorithm largely the same as what is in the OP. Keep generating numbers until you hit no duplicates. However if you keep randomly generating the same set of numbers, you will end up in the same spot.

Comment: This questioner need to print value not about solving problem of wasting CPU ticks! ya mohammad

Comment: While it's also inefficient, it's not just about CPU ticks, this solution leads to the same problem, a potential stack overflow. The code in the answer replaces the `Contains` call in the OP with a `HashSet` for finding duplicates, but the result is the same. Taking your code, imagine the RNG keeps generating `1` forever. What happens?

Comment: stack will never overflowed! `HashSet` count never exceeds over 99!

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it won't overflow. But it may run forever.

Comment: In theory of true random set you are right. but supposing above algorithm and random in programming language, all numbers seen after period of time not forever!

Comment: thanks all for commenting and replying